# Google text-text translation API

Tags: web, text, google-api, cross-platform, google-translation-api

I intended to build a language translation system (Mobile/Web Platform).And i found out that Google translation API could be use/ apply in the system. But I'm not sure if the Google Translation API is free or i have to pay for it. and what will be language we need to use while using the google translation API. 
Overall my concern is

1)programming language.
2)platform(web/ mobile).
3)Google API Is free ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What ever you like find an official client library
2. works for both.
3. See below.

Google Translate API [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/pricing) is based on usage. Translation usage is calculated in millions of characters, where 1 million = 106 characters. For more information, see the [Pricing FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/faq#pricing).

> Important: Google Translate API v2 requires billing information for
>   all accounts before you can start using the service. See instructions
>   below on how to enable billing.

Usage fees:

- Translation:

  - $20 per 1 million characters of text, where the charges are adjusted in proportion to the number of characters actually provided. For example, if you were to translate 500K characters, you would be billed $10.
  - Language Detection:
    $20 per 1 million characters of text, where the charges are adjusted in proportion to the number of characters actually provided.
- Usage limits:

  - Google Translate API has default limits of 2 million characters/day and 100,000 characters per 100 seconds (average 1000 characters/second). You can increase the first limit up to 50 million characters/day in the Cloud Platform Console by following the instructions below.
  - If you need to translate more than 50 million characters/day or 1000 characters/second